# JS Reset zoom on iPhone after page was loaded

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, browser, safari

I need to reset zoom to original page size before opening the modal on my page. I tried to do that using `viewport` and it works perfectly, but for iPhone it doesn't work at all.

```
function zoomOutMobile() {
    var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');

    if (!viewport) {
        viewport = document.createElement('meta');
        viewport.id = "viewport";
        viewport.name = "viewport";
        viewport.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewport);
    }
    viewport.content = "initial-scale=0.1";
    viewport.content = "width=" + originWidth;
}
```

I tried doing almost everything related to viewport, but it doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: @LajosArpad no, there is no errors. It seems that iPhone browser just ignores viewport changes

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes, sure. I tried almost everything. It seems that meta-viewport tag works only on page loading moment, but don't have any effect after that

Comment: Do you have a test environment which only you can see?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes. I run .net server which hosts static files including the issue stuff - html + js files. And get this stuff through LAN

Comment: That's great. Let's use your staging env as our starting point. Let's add an `alert("TEEEEST");` to that one. If you test with the given browser on your staging with this change in place, do you see the alert?

Comment: @LajosArpad sure. Moreover, each time whenever I make changes I change some diagnostics `console.log('release 22')` to make sure that they were applied

Comment: Is the problem reproducing even if you emulate iPhone browsers from a desktop browser?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes. I tried to do so on Windows Firefox (enabling mobile mode) and I got the same issue

Comment: What's the result of document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]')?

Comment: @LajosArpad <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1913273763693085">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255904/discussion-between-bibo325-and-lajos-arpad).